# C#: XPath validation

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xpath, xpathnavigator

I am working on a project and I need to extend the XPath validation. This is based on already existing code (that somebody else wrote) and apparently comes from the following code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2FKB%2FXML%2FXPathEditor%2F%2Fxpatheditor_src.zip&zep=XPathEditor%2Fexpressionvalidator.cs&obid=11150&obtid=2&ovid=2

What I understand is that here they make use of an XML document `strSample` (line 378) to validate the XPath expression. I now need to extend this so that expression like `/caseFileModel/DateToResearch + xs:dayTimeDuration('P30s')` also can be validated. When I now try to parse such an expression I get the following error:

`"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."`

I tried using a Namespace manager:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions");
```

and replaced line 252 with

```
case XPathResultType.Number: strResult = string.Format("{0}", xpathNav.Evaluate(expression, nsmgr)); 
break;
```

but then I got another error:

`"XsltContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function."`

So my question is whether somebody can explain me how the validation happens and how I can extend it?

Comment: `xs:dayTimeDuration()` is an XPath 2.0 function. Perhaps you need to use use an XPath 2.0-compatible library.

Comment: No perhaps about it. If you want to use XPath 2.0 expressions, you need an XPath 2.0 processor. There are plenty around, so long as you don't restrict yourself to Microsoft products.